# Force user to select account on Authorization MS Graph

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-identity

I want to force the user to select one of the remembered accounts or log into a new account on authorization. I know there is a `prompt` parameter which should have the value `select_account`. But I don't know how to add this to the URL in my code.

Code in the `Home.aspx`:

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties{ RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44330/Home.aspx" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

There is no `prompt` field in the `AuthenticationProperties`.

Comment: You want this to happen every time?

Comment: Yes, I want to have the option to select an account instead of automatic logging in.

Answer (score 0):

**Prompt Parameter Function:**

Client to ask the authorization server, show or do not show a login and / or consent screen

prompt=select_account  - will interrupt single sign-on providing account selection experience listing all the accounts either in session or any remembered account or an option to choose to use a different account altogether.

GET /authorize?&prompt=select_account

GET /authorize?&prompt={login,consent,select_account}& - All 3 values can be combined

GET /authorize?...&prompt={none}&

none - no show login or consent

login - request to reauthenticate

consent - request the user consent

select_account - auth server to choose list of account or single account

Example code:

```html
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX
&response_type=token
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read
&response_mode=fragment
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
&prompt=select_account
&login_hint=myuser@mycompany.com
```

[image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Comment: As said, I know this parameter should be used. But I'm not using a GET request, instead I'm using the code of Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect. But I can't find the option to add the Prompt parameter.
I don't know how I would do this with a GET request, since it needs to open the authorization menu.

Answer (score 0):

This gets modified within OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions.Notifications. See the snippet below that configures RedirectToIdentityProvider to use the select_account prompt (which is what I believe you're looking for.

```
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                    {
                        context.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = "select_account";
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        );
```

-JC